# Entity Framework updating one record deletes another

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm altering a business application to introduce a new entity SalesOrderReason. This will tie into another entity SalesOrder based on a SalesOrderReasonID field.

What I would like this code to do is to set the SalesOrderReasonID of the sales order (called from a button press - this is a desktop application).

In reality, what is happening is the first time it runs, it sets the SalesOrderReasonID - that's great. When I set the SalesOrderReasonID for the next SalesOrder it sets it correctly however it deletes a previous SalesOrder from the database which is obviously unwanted behavior.

I've had a similar issue previously where the relationship was configured incorrectly (I had put WithOne instead of WithMany) which gave the same symptoms, because of this I believe it's related to the configuration.

I've tried to configure it from the other perspective as well (SalesOrderReason config) without any success.
(Here is that attempt, I created an ICollection SalesOrdersWithReason on SalesOrderReason for this)

```
builder.HasMany(e => e.SalesOrdersWithReason)
    .WithOne(s => s.SalesOrderReason)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.SalesOrderReasonID);
```

(Sorry if this is too much code I've tried to strip away what I thought was not relevant.)

This is the SalesOrder entity.

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SalesOrderReasonID { get; set; }
    public SalesOrderReason SalesOrderReason { get; set; }
}
```

This is the SalesOrderReason entity

```
public class SalesOrderReason
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

This is my configuration using fluent API

```
public class SalesOrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SalesOrder>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SalesOrder> builder)
    {
        
        builder.HasKey(e => e.ID);

        builder.Property(e => e.ID)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(s => s.SalesOrderReason)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.SalesOrderReasonID);
    }
}
```

This is the Save method in my Repository

```
public void Save() => _context.SaveChanges();
```

It all goes wrong here when saving a change to the SalesOrderReasonID

```
private static void ChangeSalesOrderReason(SalesOrder salesOrder, int salesOrderReasonID)
{
    salesOrder.SalesOrderReasonID = salesOrderReasonID;
    SalesOrderRepository.Save();
}
```

**Edit to include UI code as requested**
The SalesOrder in this use case is an existing object which comes from a Telerik gridview row, it gets selected then the user presses a button to update the SalesOrderReason on the SalesOrder to the one in a DropDownList.

The UI is in VB.Net (Odd I know but it's part of a legacy project we're rebuilding) the above C# code is in separate C# projects added as reference in the VB project.

```
Private Sub UpdateReasonButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateReasonButton.Click
    For Each salesOrderRow As GridViewRowInfo In SalesOrderGridView.SelectedRows
        SalesOrderController.ChangeSalesOrderReason(salesOrderRow.DataBoundItem, ReasonList.SelectedValue)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: EF Core has no "repository" class nor a `Save` method. The "generic repository" **anti**pattern is notorious for breaking ORMs and even causing unexpected changes. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, and a DbSet is a Repository. The DbContext tracks *all* changes so if you wrap the same DbContext instance inside multiple different repositories, calling `SaveChanges` from one will persist the changes made by *all* repositories. That's a problem of the antipattern, not EF Core

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so if I'm understanding you correctly. You're saying I should be creating a new DBContext for every transaction?

Comment: Can you post the whole code pls. I am wondering where in you code you are calling private Static void ChangeSalesOrderReason? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where salesOrder comes from? Is it loaded from the database or it is created? if it is created it should be added into collection before SaveChanges() call.

Comment: I'm not able to post the full code as it is company property (and is way too much code to be in a stack overflow question) but I can post snippets where relevant. I have made an edit to include the UI code which calls the C# code in the OP

Comment: I see SalesOrderController.ChangeSalesOrderReason , your  repository seems  static too. It will never work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Following Panagiotis Kanavos's comment, I adjusted my DbContext to have a much shorter lifespan, I didn't have time to create a proper "Unit of Work" pattern but simply recreating the context whenever my code hit the repository seemed to do the trick.